# Reading Zebra printer status via USB on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, usb, zebra-printers

After a lot of posts in SO and Google, I could not find an answer to my problem. Most of similar questions are Windows/VB/.Net/C#/Java centric.

I need to send an ESC command to a Zebra USB printer (TTP2130) and get the status back using C/C++ . I am able to print fine (with Zebra generic driver set as default printer) using:

```
$ lpr file.prn
```

Used Zebra Toolbox to communicate in Windows and generate *.prn files with ESC commands.

But if I sent a file with a command that needs response from printer, nothing happens.

What would be the best approach to accomplish this? Maybe using libusb1.0 directly?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution after searching for 'Swecoin'. This is the old manufacturer of Zebra's TTP line of printers. [Swecoin on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swecoin).

This guy made a simple and direct app to communicate with TTP printers (ttputil): http://www.rainbow-software.org/linux/

After downloading and compiling, I was able to send commands directly:

`sudo ./ttputil enquiry sensor /dev/usblp0`

I will modify its code to fit my needs.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to contact (and thank) the original developer from his website.

Comment: My Swecoin TTP 2030 was detected fine on Debian/squeeze, and there is a /dev/lp0, but whenever I run ttputil, it just hangs and nothing ever happens. This is both as root, and as a user in the group 'lp'. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out, I need to do: `./ttputil enquiry status-enq /dev/usb/lp0` so using /dev/usb/lp0 rather than /dev/lp0

Answer (score 2):

Well I had a similar issue and in the end this post helped me a lot: https://blog.peter.skarpetis.com/archives/2005/04/07/getting-a-handle-on-usbprintsys/ it is Windows centric but the principle is the same also on Linux and Mac.